How can I use find in mongodb with 2 restrictions?
I have a collection where I have several documents that have a letter in common: example AC. I have 3 documents where the names contain AC.
But I only want to get 2 and not 3 when I put the find.
db.test.find({"Name": {"$regex": "AC"}, DC: {$not: {$elemMatch: {DC: 'text'}}}})

The result of this are the 3 documents, and I want only 2 documents with the name AC and DC is another element to exclude document 1.
EX:
{ _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b01e'), Name: 'AC 1', Place: 'Floor' }, { _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b01f'), Name: 'AC 2', Place: 'UP' }, { _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b020'), Name: 'AC 3', Place: 'Middle'})
db.test.find({"Name": {"$regex": "AC"}, DC: {$not: {$elemMatch: {DC: 'floor'}}}})

Please provide sample json documents and corresponding expected output.

{ _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b01e'), Name: 'AC 1', Place: 'Floor' }, { _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b01f'), Name: 'AC 2', Place: 'UP' }, { _id: ObjectId('671feecf55501ae50186b020'), Name: 'AC 3', Place: 'Middle'})
db.test.find({"Name": {"$regex": "AC"}, DC: {$not: {$elemMatch: {DC: 'floor'}}}})

The fieldname in the query DC doesn't match any fieldname in any document, so the $not will always be true.  $elemMatch is generally useful for querying individual elemnts in an array stored in a field.  None of the fields in the sample documents have arrays, so that isn't terribly helpful either.  Try {"Name": {"$regex": "AC"}, Place:{$ne: "Floor"}}
